# Rails5 : Select2 Gem not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am a Rails beginner and trying to use `Select2` gem in Rails application and I see it not working as expected.It is shown as normal drop down only where i am expecting search option included in it. Can some one help me please.

---

**HTML Code**

```
<tbody id="template">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <%= 
                      select_tag "order[order_placed][][itemname]", 
                      options_from_collection_for_select(Stock.all, "item_name", "item_name"), {:class => 'form-control', :id => 'select_two', :style => "width: 180px"}
                    %>


                </td>
                <td><input name="order[order_placed][][quantity]" type="text"  size='10' class="form-control" /></td>
                <td><input name="order[order_placed][][unitprice]" type="text"  size='10' class="form-control" /></td>
                <td><input name="order[order_placed][][tax]" type="text"  size='10' class="form-control"/></td>
                <td><input name="order[order_placed][][discount]" type="text"  size='10' class="form-control"/></td>
                <td><input name="order[order_placed][][itemtotalprice]" type="text" size='10' class="form-control" /></td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm sub" onClick="$(this).closest('tr').remove();">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

---

**Here is my application.js**

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, or any plugin's
// vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file. JavaScript code in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery
//= require toastr
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree  .

$(document).ready(function)(){
            $('#select_two').select2();
}
```

---

**Gem file has the related gem**

```
gem 'select2-rails'
```

Comment: If you refresh the page this is on without navigating to it via a click, does it work? My other troubleshooting tip would be to change the selector to just `$('select')`, as well as opening your javascript console and manually firing `$('select').select2()`

Comment: Thanks @JoshBrody for your quick response. But this isn't working. I've changed the selector as well.

Comment: I skimmed over your question too quick. You need to add the gem to your `application.js` — `//= require select2` (make sure it's also in your css as well)

Comment: @AbdulMuqeem lets try the solution given below and let me know for futher guidance.

Comment: Thank you @Gabbar for your response. I see this error `couldn't find file 'select2' with type 'text/css'` when added these files. I've added empty files. Page loaded as it was earlier with usual dropdown. :( Need further guidance please,

Comment: @AbdulMuqeem close the server and run bundle install and restart server again, hopefully this error will go.

Comment: @AbdulMuqeem feel/free to accept/upvote answer if it helped you.

Comment: @Gabbar. I've deleted those two empty files, and performed the mentioned Steps. Thanks to you. The error is out of ground now. Still i see the select as normal drop only. :( This is really drowning me....

Comment: @AbdulMuqeem which `two empty files` you have deleted?

Comment: @Gabbar `select2.js` and `select2.css.scss`. As it has thrown an error saying file is missed, i've added these. Once performing your steps, i deleted them as page is loaded with no issues. Anything wrong , let me know.

Comment: @AbdulMuqeem oops you didn't get the point, after adding the gem in your Gemfile you need to run bundle install and and `//= require select2` add this line in application.js and `*= require select2` this to application.css thats it. you don't need to create `select2.js` and `select2.css.scss` thes files. hope you got it.

Comment: @Gabbar Yeah.. I got it.... But this should sequence of actions should make my drop down look as Select2. But this is not happening....

Comment: Any help is appreciated....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what this is the solution but I have worked this manually on my application after following those steps

On `Gemfile`

```
gem "select2-rails"
# bundle install
```

application.js

```
//= require select2
```

Just above this `//= require_tree .` line

application.js

```
(function($){
   "use strict";
    $(document).on('ready', function(){
        $("#order_place_id").select2({
            allowClear: true,
            theme: "bootstrap"
        });
    });
}(jQuery));
```

application.css

```
*= require select2
*= require select2-bootstrap
```

HTML Code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Place Order</label>
    <select name="order[order_placed][][itemname]" id="order_place_id" class="form-control">
        <% Stock.all.each do |stock| %>
            <option value="<%= stock.item_name %>">
                <%= stock.item_name %>
            </option>
        <% end %>
    </select>
</div>
```

and finally, see the below image which I implemented

[image]

If you try this solution make sure restart your server after finished steps.

Hope to help

Comment: Thanks Chap.... This worked fine for me as well.... Thank you so much.. u r really a life saver....

Comment: Yes.. That worked perfectly fine..... but i see Select2 is not getting applied to dynamically created rows.... :( Can u help here as well please.

Comment: perhaps turbolinks if using it - change `$(document).on('ready', function(){` to `$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(){`

Answer (score 0):

add `//= require select2` in your application.js

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery
//= require toastr
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require select2
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree
```

also add in your application.css

```
*= require select2
```

also your select_tag should have name and id column like:-

```
                <%= 
                  select_tag "order[order_placed][][itemname]", 
                  options_from_collection_for_select(Stock.all, item_name, id), {:class => 'form-control', :id => 'select_two', :style => "width: 180px"}
                %>
```

for more [details](https://github.com/argerim/select2-rails)

Answer (score 0):

One other thing to note, when you add a Gem to your gemfile, you may need to restart your rails server.